# How to get list/details url in Composite C1?

Tags: c1-cms

I build menu links so I need to know where I am.

The list url looks like: *http://domain.com/list*

The detail page url looks *like: http://domain.com/list/detail*

I could search for hardcoded */list* part but it will be hardcoded.

I use the PathInfo function below and I always use 0 as parameter:

```
string PathInfo (int segment)
{
    string pathInfo = C1PageRoute.GetPathInfo()??string.Empty;
    string[] segments = pathInfo.Split('/');
    string stringValue;
    stringValue = segments.Skip(segment + 1).FirstOrDefault();
    return stringValue;
}
```

...

```
// register the use of the path info
C1PageRoute.RegisterPathInfoUsage();    
string kuruladi = PathInfo(0);
```

...

```
 @foreach (var kurul in kurullar)
    {
      string currentpageitem = "";
      if (kurul.KurulAdi == kuruladi)
      {
         currentpageitem = "current_page_item";
      }

      <li class="page_item page-item-1167 @currentpageitem">
        <a href="@kurul.KurulAdi">@kurul.KurulAdi</a>
      </li>
    }
```

Since I don't know where I am (list or detail) PathInfo(0) cannot help. An incorrect example link: *http://domain.com/Sample-Detail-Page* It should be *http://domain.com/Kurul/Sample-Detail-Page*

How can I write a much generic code to extract the exact location and then build the correct link? At least am I in list or detail, so I can use 0 or 1 as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CurrentPageNode.Url was the missing part:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-1167 @currentpageitem">
   <a href="@CurrentPageNode.Url/@kurul.KurulAdi">@kurul.KurulAdi</a>
</li>
```